# Windows DNS Manager - Transfer All Zones from Primary to Secondary

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008

Query is about Windows Server 2008 DNS manager.

I have setup a primary DNS server A, and created all zones there, it's working perfectly.

Now, I have setup a secondary DNS server B, and wants all zones from A should be synced to B without recreating them on B and also in future if I create a zone on A, it should be automatically pushed to B.

is this possible?

I know there are options to link zones one by one and make them sync, but I am looking for a bulk option that can make future syncs too.

Thanks

Comment: If both DNS servers are in the same Windows domain and the zones are AD integrated this occurs normally.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested this with Windows 2008 specifically but you could schedule a powershell script on the secondary server. Something like

```
Get-DnsServerZone -ComputerName dns.contoso.com | where {("Primary" -eq $_.ZoneType) -and ($False -eq $_.IsAutoCreated) -and ("TrustAnchors" -ne $_.ZoneName)} | %{ $_ | Add-DnsServerSecondaryZone -MasterServers 172.23.90.136 -ZoneFile "$($_.ZoneName).dns"}
```

This will grab primary zones from dns.contoso.com and create secondary zones on the local system.

(Taken from the technet documentation [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/dns-server/add-dnsserversecondaryzone?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).)

Comment: Thanks for input, but unfortunately these commands are not available for Windows 2008, they are only supported to Win 2012+